# reading files in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to read the file 'nouns.csv' which looks like this in notepad:

```
femin,femin,1,f,woman,women.
aqu,aqu,1,f,water,waters.
```

I have tried using this in SWI-Prolog:

```
18 ?- read(X).
X = end_of_file.

19 ?- see('nouns.csv').
true.

20 ?- seeing(X).
X = <stream>(000000000017F770).

21 ?- read(X).
X = end_of_file.

22 ?-
```

I have absolutely no experience with Input and Output (in any language) and I am confused. I thought read(X) would return the whole file as a string (which I thought is a stream). I want to read in each line and apply this predicate to it:

```
nounstage(Input) -->
    ["noun("],
    [Adjust],
    [")."],
    {
         append(Adjust,[46],Input)
    }.

nounlineparse(X,Y) :-
    phrase(nounstage(X),N),
    flatten(N,Y),
    asserta(Y).
```

I presumed I would make a giant list of every line in the nouns.csv, then iterate through the list and apply nounlineparse to each element. How can I get my file/stream into this giant list (or is the giant list way a bad way of doing this?).

Comment: http://www.google.com/?q=reading+files+in+Prolog

Comment: `see` and `seeing` are used for reading files of Prolog terms, which your CSV file is not.

Comment: Thanks Scott, I already tried that @KarolyHorvath: it wasn't very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SWI-Prolog, the easier route is library([csv](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=csv)).

If you need to do specific processing on read items, library([pure_input](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=pureinput)) can help you.
The basic skeleton is like

```
:- use_module(library(pure_input)).
:- use_module(library(dcg/basics)).

read_csv(Path, Records) :-
    phrase_from_file(read_csv_file(Records), Path).

read_csv_file([Tokens|Lines]) -->
    read_csv_line(Tokens), read_csv_file(Lines).
read_csv_file([]) --> [].


read_csv_line([Token]) -->
    string(TokenS), ( ".\n" ; "." ), {atom_codes(Token, TokenS)} .
read_csv_line([Token|Tokens]) -->
    string(TokenS), ",", {atom_codes(Token, TokenS)}, !, read_csv_line(Tokens).
```

You will need to pay much attention to details...

Comment: Thanks. If I do csv_read_file it gives me my giant list, which is exactly what I wanted.